# 24V to 5V Step Down - What did I do wrong?

Tags: buck

I'm new to this and trying to understand what I did wrong.

I designed a 24V to 5V buck step down around the [XL2576S-5.0E1](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809191851_XLSEMI-XL2576S-12E1_C73351.pdf) (at least, I thought I did) — however my 5V out still produces 24V.

[image]

I'm guessing I misunderstood something in the data sheet, but I’m not quite sure what.

Comment: This part has both fixed and adjustable versions. Are you sure you have the fixed one?

Comment: Yep sorry, updated my post - I'm using XL2576S-5.0E1 specifically which should be 5V fixed

Comment: @spvn87 Your 5 V output does NOT show a dotted connection to C2. Is this just a mistake in the drawing? Or something else? Because it looks like C2 is just attached to the FB pin and nothing else, without the dot.

Comment: May be the chip defected.

Comment: Everyone else in the world draws schematics with input voltage to the left, output to the right and ground down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no connections between C2, the 5 V output, and the feedback input.  You don't say whether the circuit is failing in simulation or real life, but this error will affect both.

Without this connection, the feedback input thinks the output is at 0 V.  This forces the pulse-width modulator to 100%, basically passing the input DC voltage directly to the output.

The datasheet does not mention a minimum load requirement, but it also does not say the part will regulate correctly down to zero load.  It does say the PWM range is 0% to 100%, which might imply no-load operation.

Also, ground symbols ***always*** point downward.

It looks like the U1 decal is a custom symbol.  If so, edit it such that the inputs are on the left and the outputs are on the right.  IOW, move pin 3 to the left and downward, pin 6 downward, and move pins 2 and 4 to the right.  A schematic tells the story of signal flow - signals left to right, power top to bottom.  The schematics in the datasheet are an example of this.  I'm not a fan of the feedback connection on top, but it removes crossed conductors from the drawing, a common drafting choice for this type of component.

A clear schematic makes both design errors and drafting errors more obvious.

Comment: Yep it's failing in real life. This was super, super helpful beyond just my initial problem. Really appreciate the detail you went into around signal flow!

Answer (score -2):

It's probably because there is no load connected to the output. The capacitor will quickly charge up to the supply voltage and there is nothing to pull it down to normal operating point. The reference circuits show a load but it is not specified as to what is required. Many switching supplies require a minimum load to allow regulation.

Comment: Fixed voltage stabilizator has internal divider, which can be considered a small load.

Comment: A switching regulator will never do that. There are millions of them like that with 6V3 tantalum caps at the 5V output. Try applying 24V to a 6V3 tantalum and enjoy the fire.

Comment: PStech: That is not how a switching buck regulator works.

Comment: 263983:  The loading current of the internal feedback divider is trivially small, and does not figure into any minimum load calculations.

Comment: I can see now that it is unlikely for a properly designed buck regulator to apply full supply voltage to the output. I had assumed that the circuit had been built properly, with the feedback connected to the output, and proposed an explanation based on that assumption. It is still good practice to have a minimal load connected in order to achieve good regulation. I didn't think my answer deserved two downvotes, but I am new here. I guess I will need to tread more carefully in the future, to avoid getting dinged.